# Loading Gensim FastText Model with Callbacks Fails

Tags: python, callback, gensim, jupyter-lab, fasttext

After creating a FastText model using Gensim, I want to load it but am running into errors seemingly related to callbacks.

The code used to create the model is

```py
TRAIN_EPOCHS = 30
WINDOW = 5
MIN_COUNT = 50
DIMS = 256

vocab_model = gensim.models.FastText(sentences=model_input,
                                     size=DIMS,
                                     window=WINDOW,
                                     iter=TRAIN_EPOCHS,
                                     workers=6,
                                     min_count=MIN_COUNT,
                                     callbacks=[EpochSaver("./ftchkpts/")])

vocab_model.save('ft_256_min_50_model_30eps')
```

and the callback `EpochSaver` is defined as

```py
from gensim.models.callbacks import CallbackAny2Vec

class EpochSaver(CallbackAny2Vec):
    '''Callback to save model after each epoch and show training parameters '''

    def __init__(self, savedir):
        self.savedir = savedir
        self.epoch = 0
        os.makedirs(self.savedir, exist_ok=True)

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        savepath = os.path.join(self.savedir, f"ft256_{self.epoch}e")
        model.save(savepath)
        print(f"Epoch saved: {self.epoch + 1}")
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.savedir, f"ft256_{self.epoch-1}e")):
            os.remove(os.path.join(self.savedir,  f"ft256_{self.epoch-1}e"))
            print("Previous model deleted ")
        self.epoch += 1
```

Aside from the type of model, this is identical to my process for Word2Vec which worked without issue. However when I open another file and try to load the model with

```py
from gensim.models import FastText
vocab = FastText.load(r'vocab/ft_256_min_50_model_30eps')
```

I'm greeted with the error

> `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'EpochSaver' on <module '__main__'>`

What can I do to get the vocabulary to load so I can create the embedding layer for my keras model? If it's relevant, this is happening in JupyterLab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This extra difficulty loading models with custom callbacks is a [known, open issue](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2136) (at least through `gensim-3.8.1` and October 2019).

You can see discussions of possible workarounds and fixes there – and the gensim team is considering simply disabling the auto-saving of callbacks at all, requiring them to be re-specified for each later `train()`/etc call that needs them.

You may be able to load existing models saved with your custom callbacks by importing those same callback classes, as the same names, into the code context where you're doing a `load()`.

You could save callback-free versions of your trained models by blanking the model's `callbacks` property to its empty default value, just before you `save()`, eg:

```
model.callbacks = ()
model.save(save_path)
```

Then, you wouldn't need to do any special importing of custom classes before a `load()`. (Of course if you again needed callback functionality on the re-loaded model, they'd then have to be explicitly reestablished after `load()`).

Comment: Thanks. Reimporting the callback class fixed that error, but now I get a KeyError while trying to load it (???). Looks like I'm just going to have to train it again.

Comment: I'd have to see the exact `KeyError` & error stack to know what that might be, and if there might be a workaround to load your file.

Comment: The KeyError is for `news`, which was the vector that ended up at index `0` for my previous word2vec model, if that's significant. The full error stack is here: http://codepad.org/Vmay7knq
I appreciate your help.

Comment: That's a very surprising error because the code in questions is merely iterating over an actual list of words in the model (`wv.index2word`) that should in normal operation match 1-to-1 with keys in the dictionary (`wv.vocab`). If you'd done any vocabulary-expansion or manual tampering with the vocabulary, I'd suspect it may have broken the class invariant assumption that the `index2word` and `vocab.keys()` are always the same lenth and same set-of-strings. (If debugging live, as if in a Jupyter notebook with `%debug` after receiving that exception, those are the 1st vars I'd check.)

Comment: I didn't do anything between training and saving it, and likewise have the same error with the callback-saved versions. This is vexing. It's not loaded so I can't check the vars, but if there's anything in the files themselves I can check for clues please let me know. I'm sorry I can't provide access to the actual files.

Comment: Are you using the latest gensim? If executing your `load()` in some interactive REPL (like `ipython` or a Jupyter notebook), you *can* use the `%debug` mode to view the (somewhat loaded but not-yet-assigned to your variable) model's state, as of the point the exception was raised. If you're really just doing train/save/load, might the error be reproducible with the same code but just a tiny bit of synthetic training data?

Comment: If you can in fact reliably trigger the error, even after blanking the `callbacks` to fully avoid the original `Can't get attribute` error, I'd suggest posting that problem as a separate question with full details/errors/code/stack in that new question. (It's very likely a problem with a very different cause/solution than the original, understood-with-workarounds, `callbacks` issue.)

Comment: Okay, it's been created as a new question with (what I think are) the relevant details.